# bash: evaluate substitution and replace on command line

Tags: bash, command-line-interface, readline

Someone once showed me how to replace the current command (input line) with the output from a substitution.I suspect it is a readline function but can not remember which.The idea is basically that if you type in something like

```
$ cd `pwd` <READLINE-MACRO such as M-b or C-a>
```

then the command line will become:

```
$ cd /home/username/files
```

and after you run the command the history file will have `cd /home/username/files` as opposed to 'cd `pwd`'

Comment: What would happen if you try to search in the [Bash documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Miscellaneous-Commands)?

Comment: I don't think `bash` lets you complete command substitutions; `zsh` may, however.

Comment: I know that bash does this and I did try too look in man bash and man readline, but could not find what I was looking for.

Comment: In `bash`, I know it is possible to substitute commands such as `!$` after pressing space. But, you need to configure it in `.bashrc` first. Example, `ls !$` will become `ls /home/pax/`

Comment: The zsh expands backtick substitutions as you desire with a <TAB>. Maybe you saw a zsh user in action?

Comment: No, I did not see zsh in action. This was bash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [§ 8.4.8 "Some Miscellaneous [Readline] Commands" of the *Bash Reference Manual*](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Miscellaneous-Commands):

> `shell-expand-line (M-C-e)`
>
> > Expand the line as the shell does. This performs alias and history expansion as well as all of the shell word expansions (see [Shell Expansions](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Expansions)).

So, just type your command:

```
cd `pwd`
```

Then hit Alt+Ctrl+e to effect the command-substitution:

```
cd /home/username/files
```

Then hit Enter.

Comment: Looks like lanzz told me to where to look already. I should really skim the bash docs entirely some time. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are finding such case: first you run

> cd `pwd`

and then when you run:

> `!cd`

it will seach your history cd command and replace `pwd` to /home/username/files

is it?

Comment: No, not really. `!string' looks in history for the most recent command starting with string and runs it again. It's used to re-execute previous commands, not to put the output of a command in the input line.